# QML: one signal, multiple slots, possible?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to figure out the best way for a QML object to send out a signal and for many other QML elements to respond to it. Normally, if you create `signal mySignal` then you have a handler automatically created for you called `onMySignal` but that handler exists only within the same element that created the signal.

A particularly inelegant solution could be to store an array of QML elements you want updated when a signal occurs, and then in your handler you loop through all those elements and do what you need.

I'd be surprised if there wasn't an easier way. Am I missing an obvious use case of the signal-slot mechanism in QML?

Comment: there should be a method of creating custom connections

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [Connections](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qml-qtquick2-connections.html) component in QML to achieve this

The `Item` with the signal we want to catch:

```
MyItem {
  id: itemWithSignal

  onMySignal: {
    console.log("I am sending my signal");
  }
}
```

In another `Item` we use the `Connections` component:

```
MyOtherItem {
  id: itemSomewhereElse

  Connections {
    target: itemWithSignal

    onMySignal: {
      console.log("itemWithSignal just emitted its signal!");
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use `connect()` in `QML` so it would be something like this:

```
MyOtherItem {
  id: itemSomewhereElse

  onMyOtherSignal: {
    console.log("My signal is connected!");
  }

  Component.onCompleted: {
    itemWithSignal.mySignal.connect(itemSomewhereElse.myOtherSignal);
  }
}
```